# Need help with the integration part

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces

> Consider the Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$. A hilbertian basis
> \begin{equation} \varphi_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!2^n\sqrt{\pi}}} e^{-x^2/2} H_n(x), \quad n=0,1,2,...
> \end{equation}
> where $H_n(x)$ are the Hermite polynomials. Given the vector $\psi(x) = e^{-x^2/2}(a+bx+cx^2)$ from $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$. Find $\| \psi \|$ and the components of $\psi$ in the given basis.

So I started with
\begin{equation} \| \psi \|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big| e^{-x^2/2}(a+bx+cx^2) \Big|^2 dx
\end{equation}

With respect to the second part, $\psi = \sum a_n \varphi_n$ ,the component $a_n$

\begin{equation} a_n =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi^*_n \ \psi \ dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!2^n\sqrt{\pi}}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-x^2}(a+bx+cx^2) H_n(x) dx
\end{equation}

I couldn't manage to resolve the integrals. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: My first guess would be to try to write $a+bx+cx^2$ as a linear combination of $H_0$, $H_1$, $H_2$ (a 3-d linear algebra problem), and then use orthogonormality of the $\varphi_n$ to compute $\| \psi\|$.

Comment: $\displaystyle a+bx+cx^2=a_0H_0(x)+a_1H_1(x)+a_2H_2(x)$, and you can find $a_{1,2,3}$ using the explicite forms of $H_{1,2,3}(x)$ (for example, using the Rodrigues' formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula )

Comment: $a_0 = a+c/2$, $a_1 = b/2$ and $a_2 = c/4$. How can I get ride of the modulus in the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given
$$ b_{n} = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \, (a + b x + c x^2) \, H_{n}(x) \, dx $$
then by using
\begin{align}
1 &= H_{0}(x) \\
x &= \frac{1}{2} \, H_{1}(x) \\
x^2 &= \frac{1}{4} \, ( H_{2}(x) + 2 \, H_{0}(x)) \\
\sqrt{\pi} \, 2^n \, n! \, \delta_{n, m} &= \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \, H_{m}(x) \, H_{n}(x) \, dx 
\end{align}
the integral becomes
\begin{align}
b_{n} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \left(a + \frac{c}{2}\right) \, H_{0}(x) + \frac{b}{2} \, H_{1}(x) + \frac{c}{4} \, H_{2}(x) \right) \, H_{n}(x) \, e^{-x^2} \, dx \\
&= \sqrt{\pi} \left[ \left(a + \frac{c}{2} \right) \, \delta_{n,0} + b \, \delta_{n,1} + 2 c \, \delta_{n, 2} \right].
\end{align}
This gives

Comment: Very useful!! Thanks